# try..catch macro wrapper equivalent in cython

Tags: c++, python, macros, cython

I'm wrapping a large number of C++ functions that can raise an exception if the underlying socket connection is lost. While I have figured out how to wrap my "get connection" function to re-establish the connection and/or try other available servers in a list, I cannot figure out a solution to create a try..except wrapper to provide to the 80+ C++ functions.

```python
#-- client.pxd ---

cdef extern from "rpc/RpcService.h": 
    cdef cppclass RpcServiceClient:
        void getProject(ProjectT&, Guid& id) nogil except +

cdef extern from "client.h":
    cdef cppclass Client:
        RpcServiceClient proxy() nogil 

    cdef Client* getClient() nogil except +


#-- module.pxd ---

cdef inline Client* conn() except *:
   # wrap getClient() here with try..except if the 
   # connection was never established

cpdef inline get_project(Guid& guid):
    cdef: 
        ProjectT projT  # cpp object
        Project project # cdef python class

    # this would catch fine in my conn() wrapper
    # if the connection had never been established
    # the first time. But if the existing connection
    # suddenly drops, it will be getProject() that
    # raises the exception
    conn().proxy().getProject(projT, guid)

    project = initProject(projT)
    return project
```

Any tips on how I can wrap all of these C++ functions in something like a `try_call()` ?
If this were pure python, I could simply do something like this:

```python
def try_call(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    # try fn(*args, **kwargs) and handle

try_call(conn().proxy().getProject, projT, guid)
```

But obviously I cannot pass these cython functions as python objects (or maybe I can?).

Or something like this in C++:

```python
TRY_CALL_OR_RECONNECT
conn().proxy().getProject(projT, guid)
END_TRY_CALL_OR_RECONNECT
```

Comment: If you know how to do this in C++, and in pure Python… is there a reason you have to do it in Cython? Why not write either a C++ wrapper that sticks the macro on each function, then wrap that in Cython, or write a Python wrapper around the Cython code that does the equivalent from the Python side?

Comment: Just going off intuition here, but I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to pass cython functions as python objects. After all, library functions implemented in C etc. can also be passed as python function objects.

Comment: @abarnert: I cannot modify the original C++ functions that I am wrapping. There is no where in the c++ space for me to place these macro wrappers around each call. I am doing this in cython because the entire module is cython. Otherwise I would then have to write a pure python wrapper that imports the cython module, and further wraps every call.

Comment: @azgult: Because they are not first class python objects. When I try to pass them like I would a python function object, I get an error.

Comment: I didn't mean modify the original C++ functions; I meant write a C++-to-C++ wrapper and modify that wrapper (where "write a wrapper" may mean "write a Python script that auto-generates a wrapper from the headers"), then wrap that wrapper in Cython. That may not be feasible in all use cases, but it certainly is in many.

Comment: As for "I would have to write a pure python wrapper…" Yes, but so what? It's pretty common to create a `_foo.so` that provides a thin-as-possible wrapper around `libfoo`, and then a `foo.py` that provides a more Pythonic interface around that. Even the stdlib has examples.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can very definitely pass around both `def`- and `cdef`-defined functions from Cython in Python. If that isn't working for you, please post the code and errors. Or are you trying to pass the C++ functions around, rather than functions you defined in Cython? (Also, any particular reason you're using `cpdef` and `inline`? Do you really need these functions available to Cython, and inlined if called from Cython?)

Comment: @abarnert: I am not trying to pass def and cdef defined cython functions. I am trying to pass the C++ functions. That is my problem. My cython wrapper is already pythonic. What I am trying to avoid is having to do a pure python wrapper SOLEY to wrap every single call with a try..except. Also, that would not help me much for the methods of my classes.

Comment: @abarnert: And for the cpdef inline, I do expose them as a function to python, and reuse them in methods of classes elsewhere.

Comment: Keep in mind that a pure Python wrapper can be built dynamically. And it can wrap methods just as easily as free functions just by wrapping the classes in subclasses (or, if you prefer, by monkeypatching). Also, making your Cython code as pythonic as possible so you don't need a pure Python wrapper is a great idea in principle… but when doing so requires features that Cython doesn't have, it may not be a good idea in practice. Making your Cython code as thin as possible and then writing pythonic pure Python may be a lot easier. (Of course it can also lead to writing something as messy as PIL…)

Comment: @abarnert: I really appreciate your input, as no one else has submitted any answers. If the answer is "you cannot accomplish this with any cython mechanism" then I would accept that as the answer. I know very well how to write a python wrapper, if that were the only resort. It still absolutely does not solve my direct problem, because within say 10 lines of a function I have defined, there will be one line that needs to be caught for a connection error, the connection remade, and the line re-run. I would not like to wrap that entire function and re-run all of its code. Just the C++ call.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check out decorators

```
def try_wrapper(x):
    try:
        x()
    except:
        doSomethingElse()

@try_wrapper
def defYouWantToWrap():
    doSomething()
```

this may not be the best tutorial, but hopefully it can point you in the right direction

Comment: this only works for python functions, not for when I call c++ functions